# MediaWiki API: search for pages in specific namespace, containing a substring (NOT a prefix)

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I want to scrape pages from a list of Wikipedia Categories, for which there isn't a 'mother category'. In this case, dishes -- I want to get a list of all of the pages like `Category:Vegetable Dishes`, `Category: Italian Dishes`, then scrape and tag the pages in them. I know how to search for pages in a known category, but there are hundreds of categories containing the substring dishes + it feels like it should be easy to list them.

However, [mediaWiki allcategories search](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allcategories) seems to only allow search by prefix (e.g. from and to results), and while [*old* opensearch documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aOpensearch) still allows search by substring, this is no longer supported. (see [updated API docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=opensearch) + it also doesn't work if I try it)

This is [very doable in the wikipedia browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=Dishes&ns14=1&fulltext=Search+Category+namespace&fulltext=Search&searchToken=bobtaaf2a4jcdlfg3lpgwtszs), to the point where I think it might be quicker to just scrape search results, but I wonder if I'm missing something?

[image: screenshot of search query]

Comment: Opensearch is meant for browser integration, as you might guess from the notice on the top of that doc page. Also it never allowed search by substring; it is a prefix search meant for typeahead. Use the normal search API.

Comment: hey @Tgr - yes, I’ve been trying that, but not sure how to restrict search to the categories namespace while still doing a substring search. (e.g. can’t seem to do regular search on ‘allCategories’

Comment: allcategories is not search, it's a list of all categories. There is a [search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search), with namespace filters and many other functions (it's pretty much identical to the search web UI). It doesn't do substring match per se, but you can search for words in the title.

Comment: ah! Apologies -- not sure how I missed this before! I thought I was already on the search API, apparently not. Thanks so much for your help! Once I have a correct query I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tgr, for pointing out that I'd missed the regular [search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search), which allows for both a text search, specified namespace, and so on.

The correct query for my instance is:

`curl "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srnamespace=14&srsearch=Dishes&format=json"`

thanks!